# What does this question mean by Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the vector space $M_{2\times2}$. Its vectors are $2 \times 2$ matrices with real
> entries. The addition operation is addition of matrices, and scalar multiplication is
> scalar multiplication of matrices.
>
> (a) What is the zero vector of this vector space?
>
> (b) Is the set of all $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrices a subspace of $M_{2\times2}$?
>
> (c) Is the set of all $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices a subspace of $M_{2\times2}$?

What does this question mean by diagonal matrices?

Comment: Diagonal; matrices have $a_{12}=a_{21}=0$.

Comment: A matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close for "Missing context or other details". The question is about a standard definition. Closure+comments suggesting they look in their notes (or some other interaction) would be helpful. Closing the question without comment is actively unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with square matrices of order n (i.e. with n rows and n columns), a matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ is said to be *diagonal* if the entry $a_{ij}$ is zero for all indices $i\neq j$. Thus only the diagonal entries (that's how we call the entries $a_{ij}$ with i=j) can be nonzero.